# PixiJS: Add hole into graphics object

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I'm using [PixiJS](http://www.pixijs.com/) library. I want to create holes in graphics object. To do that I have search and tried loads of way but could not come up with any solution.

Initially I was thinking this library would have support for non zero winding rule so I can accomplish my goal easily but it does not support winding rule so I fail on that attempt.

Meanwhile I found some strange behavior with drawing. I have posted a bug at [github](https://github.com/GoodBoyDigital/pixi.js/issues/1755). I don't know whether is it related to adding hole but mentioned here because one who interested to help me out it might be helpful to investigate this case better way.

Other solution that I have come up with is that I can do it using something called *[opposite of Masking](https://github.com/GoodBoyDigital/pixi.js/issues/1639)*. I have tried this one also but don't know how to do it with graphics objects and also worry about that would it work for complex objects with thousands of cut.

Below is the simple test that I'm trying to reproduce. There is three rectangles on top of each other and top most (red rectangle) has two holes. For simple test round hole is taken but that could be in any shape.

I'm stuck at this stage and invested loads of time but still have no result. Any help would be really appreciable.

[image]

Comment: What exactly is *your goal* ?

Comment: @LJ_1102 create a hole into 2d shape

Comment: I thought Pixi.js just displays images. If those images have transparent areas they get drawn transparently (or not drawn). So what's the question? Either make an image in your favorite program with transparent holes where you want them or use an offscreen canvas 2d to make the image you want and use that for your images in pixi.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Pixi v3.0.3**

Currently there is no direct native function available to add holes inside graphics object. Indeed it can be done using mask but I have made a handy implementation for that using [earcut](https://github.com/mapbox/earcut) so no more masking and sprite to create holes.

Checkout full thread [here](https://github.com/GoodBoyDigital/pixi.js/issues/1755).

Comment: For lost googles, in Pixi v6, here is a sample with polygons:
```
  g.drawPolygon(...path);
  if (holesPaths.length) {
    g.beginHole()
    holesPaths.forEach(holePath => g.drawPolygon(holePath));
    g.endHole()
  }
```
At the time of writing, there is an `addHole` function in the doc, but it doesn't seem to exist anymore.

Answer (score 3):

As of Pixi.js v3, you can now use any sprite as a mask for another sprite, so you can create an alpha transparent png with a white rectangle and black circles and use that to create the 'holes' in your other sprite.

Comment: Indeed but I made quite handy implementation. Checkout [here](https://github.com/GoodBoyDigital/pixi.js/issues/1755). The last answer of my own question.

Answer (score 0):

The WebGL built-in way to do that is to use `gl.blendFunc(gl.ZERO,gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`.

This blend operation creates a hole instead of stacking images. It also takes into consideration semi-transparence. It is the equivalent of the `xor` `globalCompositeOperation` on regular canvas.

---

In order to use `gl.blendFunc(gl.ZERO,gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);` with PIXI, you will need to modify 1 line of PIXI source code.

In the function `WebGLRenderer.prototype._mapGlModes`, change

`this.blendModes[CONST.BLEND_MODES.EXCLUSION] = [gl.ONE, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA];`

into

`this.blendModes[CONST.BLEND_MODES.EXCLUSION] = [gl.ZERO, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA];`

Then you can set `mySprite.blendMode = PIXI.BLEND_MODES.EXCLUSION` and it will work.

---

One problem with that method however is that, like regular canvas, the holes generated will be transparent. In your example, this means that the holes will be the same color than the canvas background (black) rather than green.

One way to fix that is to stack multiple webgl canvas on top of each other with the option `{transparent:true}`.